# Why are my median and mean not returning anything?

Tags: arrays, return, median, mode

The following code is trying to find the averages of a set of numbers in C, but the median and the mean both do not return anything. How do I make it so the mean and the median both return a float? Am I returning an invalid value or?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

float mean(int arr[], int size){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return ((float)sum/size);
 }

int range(int arr[], int size){
    int smallest = arr[0];
    int largest = arr[0];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(smallest>arr[i]){
            smallest = arr[i];
        }   if(largest<arr[i]){
             largest = arr[i];
        }
     }  int difference = largest - smallest;
    return difference;
}

int mode(int arr[], int size){
    int maxValue = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
            if(arr[j] == arr[i]){
                count++;
            }
        }   if(count > maxCount){
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }   return maxValue;
}

float median(int arr[], int size){
    qsort(arr, size, sizeof(int), compare);
    float middleOfArray = size/2;
    int roundedMiddleOfArray = rint(middleOfArray);
    if(ceilf(middleOfArray) == middleOfArray){
        return((float)arr[roundedMiddleOfArray]);
    }
    else{
        return((float)arr[roundedMiddleOfArray] - arr[roundedMiddleOfArray-1]);
}
}

int main(){
    int array[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int newMean = mean(array, 5);
    int newRange = range(array, 5);
    int newMode = mode(array,5);
    int newMedian = median(array, 5);
    printf("The mean is : %f \n", newMean);
    printf("The range is : %d \n",newRange);
    printf("The mode is : %d \n",newMode);
    printf("The median is : %f \n", newMedian);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way you fix it is by declaring the mean and the median as floats not ints (in main).